# What is the the least possible value of the gradient of the curve $y=(2x+a)(x-2a)^2$ at the point where x = 1, as a varies?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

> What is the the least possible value of the gradient of the curve $y=(2x+a)(x-2a)^2$ at the point where x = 1, as a varies?

The first derivative is $2(x-2a)(3x-a)$, the second derivative is $12x-14a$.

How do I find the least possible value of the gradient from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the gradient (first derivative). Substitute $x=1$ into it:
$$2(1-2a)(3-a)=2(2a^2-7a+3)=4(a^2-7/2a+3/2)=4((a-7/4)^2-25/16)$$
The least possible value of the gradient at $1$ is thus attained when this polynomial in $a$ achieves *its* minimum. I have completed the square above, showing that the minimal value is $-\frac{25}4$.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure whether the gradient meant the first derivative or the second one